# Join a property of an anonymous type with a list of elements

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, c#-6.0

I have an `IQueryable<Anonymous>`

```
Anonymous
{
   field = BatchNumber,
   list = list of Employees
}

Employees
{
 PersonId,
 HireDate ....
}
```

and I have an IQueryable of Person

```
Person
{
 PersonId,
 Name
}
```

I want to use the Join Method from linq, not a query expression and the result should be an IQueryable with

BatchNumber and Name

(the batchNumber of all employees and their names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your models like this:

```
class Anonymous
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

class Employee
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    ...
}

class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And objects like this:

```
IQueryable<Anonymous> anonymous = ...;
IQueryable<Person> persons = ...;
```

For each `Anonymous` you can generate new objects with `BatchNumber` and `Name` joining `Employees` property with `persons` object by `PersonId` property:

```
var result = anonymous.SelectMany(a => 
                                  a.Employees.Join(persons, 
                                                   e => e.PersonId, 
                                                   p => p.PersonId, 
                                                   (e, p) => new 
                                                   {
                                                       BatchNumber = a.Field,
                                                       Name = p.Name
                                                   }));
```

This produces a collection of objects containing two properties: `BatchNumber` and `Name`